# How to solve java.netsocketException: connection reset from HTTPs Request port 443 using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to perform load test using HTTP Request Sampler and i tried 1 https request for 1 user with IP address and port (10.198.53.89:443) which is a load balancer IP address,but I am getting the below
-Response code: Non HTTP response code java.netsocketException.
-Response message: Non HTTP response message: connection reset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlAll.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPfXi.jpg)

[jmeter.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdsvG.jpg)

I tried to test the connection from my local PC to (10.198.53.89:443) by telnet command and was succeeded to connect.
I tried to run the request using SoapUI with same IP address and port ( 10.198.53.89:443 ) and it was is working good and get success response.
I tried to run same https request using Jmeter

---

,but with different IP address and port (10.198.53.63:4447) and the request was working good and received success response.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say anything by looking into photos of your screen.

I would recommend the following:

1. [Enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
   ```
2. [Enable Java debug logging for SSL/TLS connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

   ```
   javax.net.debug=all
   ```

Then re-run your test and inspect [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file and [console output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), it might be the case you will need to tune JMeter/Java configuration when it comes to enabled SSL protocols and their versions.

Comment: I found in jmeter.log error >> [read] I/O error: connection reset